# Running F.lux (Flux) or Redshift with Multiple Monitors with Nvidia Optimus

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I have tried installing F.lux and then Redshift, and configured them to run on multiple monitors with no success. I wonder if my setup, which includes Nvidia Optimus setup using Bumblebee could be the cause for this failure.

Both programs seems to run fine on my laptop screen, but my external monitor via VGA does not adjust its color with my laptop screen. Has anyone had a similar experience, or been able to get a color adjustment program working on an external monitor using a Nvidia Optimus laptop? The Optimus situation has me configured to run the external monitor using `intel-virtual-output` and Xrandr on Nvidia's drivers, so I wonder if this situation has an effect on my ability to run the F.lux or Redshift programs.

Here are some of the guides I followed:

https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet/issues/18

http://justgetflux.com/linux.html

http://jonls.dk/redshift/

https://gist.github.com/bcomnes/4243805

I have a W520 ThinkPad with Intel 3000HD and Nvidia Quadro 1000M chipsets, running Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and Windows 7 dual-boot.

Comment: did you try `sudo-apt-get install redshift` 
and then from `terminal` just `redshift -O 4500`

you can always change the number 4500 to any number,

Answer (score 1):

In my case [this topic helped](https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet/issues/16).
Herf prepared brilliant patch for xflux which has to replace the original `/usr/bin/xflux` and it works like a charm.